# Image CSS with and height relative to file's dimensions not container's

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image nested inside a fluid layout as follows:

```
<div id="full_image">
  <div class="t">
    <div class="t_c">
      <img src="image.jpg" />
      <div id="close"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the CSS:

```
#full_image{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}
#full_image img{
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
}
#full_image #close{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background: url('../images/close2.png');
    cursor: pointer;
}
.t{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.t_c{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, the `max-width`, `max-height` properties on the `#full_image img` selector seem to only change the height based on the image file's dimensions. So for example, the image is 600px x 600px, the CSS would resize the image to 540px x 540px despite the `#full_image` divider being 300px x 300px.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R8smE/2/

Thanks.

Comment: You are using `height: 1000px` so what do you expect?

Comment: @chadocat this was because i used jQuery to fade in the full_image divider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess its what you want
http://jsfiddle.net/R8smE/6/

Now its vertically centered

```
.t{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#full_image img{
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: The point in using display:table was so I could centre it vertically.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't think about using transform property, I skimmed past that possibility on a blog somewhere but didn't think it would be suitable, but it does a grand job.